# plotting line graphy for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataframe with about 10000 values like

```
    fruit .    count
    -------------------
    apples     100
    onions     84
    banan      40
```

Now I don't care if I can see the fruit name but want the count on a line graph.

I use `df.plot(x ='fruit', y='count', kind = 'line')` 
But the issue I'm having is that the graph has values from like 1 million and my graph looks really small. Any way to make this prettier so my graph fits properly.

Comment: show you plot result

Comment: Use matplotlib: `plt.plot('fruit', 'count', data=df, marker="o")`

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi done.

Comment: @John Constantine use log scale on y axis

Answer (score 1):

If you use matplotlib (which is being called by `df.plot()`) you can set the axis to logarithmic scale.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(df["Count"])
plt.yscale("log")
plt.show()
```

The only other thing you could do is split it into multiple plots.

Comment: Is there a way to add ticks on xaxis I get an error saying list not callable

Comment: As you would think, there is a ```plt.set_yticks``` method. I suggest you Just Google it, matplotlib hast a pretty good documentation. Can you give more Info in the Error? In which line does it get thrown?

Comment: @ValeKnappich `set_xticks()` is for axes instances (i.e. `ax.set_xticks()`) the corresponding method in the `pyplot` module is `xticks()` (i.e. `plt.xticks()`)